# Getting File not found error while trying to read the data from .xlsx file from internal storage

Tags: java, android

i am trying to read the data from .xlsx file which is stored in internal storage but while trying to access the file getting the file not found error

i have tried my best to solve the problem but not able to get the answer

is there any solution for this

here is my code

```
  if (v == btnChoose) {

            Intent intent = new Intent()
                    .setType("*/*")
                    .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);            
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a 
            file"), 1);
        }
    }

      @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
    Intent 
     data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if ((data != null) && (data.getData() != null)) {
            Uri selectedFile = data.getData();
            String PathHolder = data.getData().getPath();
            try {
                InputStream stream = 
     getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                onReadClick(stream);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(selectedFile), 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}

      public void onReadClick(InputStream filepath) {
    printlnToUser("reading XLSX file from resources");

    try {

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(filepath);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int rowsCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = 
      workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        for (int r = 0; r < rowsCount; r++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
            int cellsCount = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
            for (int c = 0; c < cellsCount; c++) {
                String value = getCellAsString(row, c, formulaEvaluator);
                String cellInfo = "r:" + r + "; c:" + c + "; v:" + value;
                printlnToUser(cellInfo);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        printlnToUser(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Error

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.smartloan.smtrick.electionapp, PID: 18818
org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found
at org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:72)
at org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:178)
at org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:92)
at org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory.newInstance(XMLEventFactory.java:30)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.PackagePropertiesMarshaller.(PackagePropertiesMarshaller.java:41)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:161)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.(OPCPackage.java:141)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:97)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:324)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:295)
at com.smartloan.smtrick.electionapp.Activity_ReadPdf.onReadClick(Activity_ReadPdf.java:181)
at com.smartloan.smtrick.electionapp.Activity_ReadPdf.onActivityResult(Activity_ReadPdf.java:155)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8249)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4958)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5006)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2068)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7551)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.

Comment: `intent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
` You better remove that as it makes no sense. You cannot grant anything here.

Comment: `String PathHolder = data.getData().getPath();` You should have a look at the value returned by .getPath() and then realise that it is no file system path that you can use for the File class. Instead have a look at uri.toString() to see the content scheme you got.

Comment: `InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());`

Comment: i'll try this out thank you

Comment: org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found
getting this error now

Comment: Please show complete updated code in a new code block.

Comment: i have updated the code

Comment: Well.. and does it work? `InputStream filepath` Please do not name your input stream a file path. It makes your code unreadble.

Comment: `onReadClick(InputStream)` make that `onReadClick(Uri)` and call with `onReadClick(data.getData()`. Open the stream in onReadClick.

Comment: getting the same error

Comment: Please update your code here ... And post the stack trace. Post the value of used uri.toString() too.

Comment: `printlnToUser("reading XLSX file from resources");` ???? `onReadClick` you better call that `readWorkbook(Uri)` to make your code better readable.

Comment: updated the error

Comment: You better update your code. `readWorkbook(Uri)` is missing...

Comment: the problem is not over there the problem is at this line  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(filepath);